# Windows 10 Video Driver Out-dated

Tags: pc, graphics-card

When I try to run Stonehearth an Error message pops up saying...

```
Could not find OpenGL.
Press 'okay' to go to stonehearth.net to learn how to upgrade your graphics card drivers.
```

I was able to run the game fine on my Windows 7's OS, but not on Windows 10's OS.   I have tried using compatibility mode,  (Going under properties and forcing it to run in Windows 7 mode) but it doesn't make a difference.

Computer Specs.

- OS - Windows 10
- BIOS - Hewlett-Packard (Version 786G6 v01.03 | 2009)
- CPU - AMD Athlon II X2 (2 Cores, 2 Threads)
- RAM - 4 GB RAM (Dual 2 GB)
- Microsoft Basic Display Adapter (32-Bit)
- GPU - ATI Radeon HD 4200

Comment: This is just one of the many reasons we should wait for windows 10.

Comment: "Microsoft Basic Display Adapter" is not a GPU. It's the default display driver that is used en lieu of actual drivers for your GPU (which got removed during the upgrade). If you don't know what graphics card you actually have, you can try running `dxdiag` (should still exist in Win 10), and check what is listed under *Device* on the *Display* tab. Alternatively, both NVIDIA and AMD/ATI have autodetect tools on their websites to help you find a driver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must install driver for your GPU "Microsoft Basic Display Adapter (32-Bit)", otherwise it won't open, as OpenGL comes with drivers. As this is a generic GPU, you probably should install all drivers of your computer, your vendor probably packed it with your drivers.

(also, it is time to upgrade, GPUs of some smartwatches and most phones are as powerful as your GPU, maybe even better)

Comment: It's a generic driver not a generic GPU. We don't know what sort of video card he has on his machine. He could have a GeForce GTX Titan X for all we know.

Comment: @RossRidge, yep, that is how I think at Microsoft at 18 Celcius (64.4 Fahrenheit). Mind == blo-- frozen.